# display flex - keeping last element in full width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to keep my 3d element with full width of the `flex` container. but not getting the reuslt. any one suggest me the right way for `ie11` here?

```css
.parent{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  padding:0 40px;
}

.child{
  flex:0 0 30%;
  border:1px dashed green;
}

.child.last{
/* not working */
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">one</div>
  <div class="child">two</div>
  <div class="child last">three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To enable for the last `child` to wrap and be 100% wide, add `flex-wrap: wrap` to `parent`  and use `flex-basis` on last `child`.

```css
.parent{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  padding:0 40px;
}

.child{
  flex:0 0 30%;
  border:1px dashed green;
}

.child.last{
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">one</div>
  <div class="child">two</div>
  <div class="child last">three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: To be clear, this makes the last child _always_ 100% width.

Comment: @MarsAndBack -- Yes, and that is what OP asked for. There are other solutions if one doesn't want that. Here's one that works different: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48225892/2827823

Answer (score 4):

**To make the last child 100%-width only after wrapping...**

Use `flex: 1`:

The flex property specifies the length of the item, relative to the rest of the flexible items inside the same container. It makes the flex item flexible and sets the flex basis to zero, resulting in an item that receives the specified proportion of the remaining space.

```css
.parent{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  padding:0 40px;
}

.child{
  flex:0 0 30%;
  border:1px dashed green;
}

.child.last{
  width:100%;

  /* SOLUTION */
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">one</div>
  <div class="child">two</div>
  <div class="child last">three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works nicely if you want 100% width only when items wrap.

Comment: @MarsAndBack -- It would work if they will wrap, which these flex items never will, unless one tell them to, using e.g. `flex-wrap: wrap;`