# FlexBox align (stretch) last Item

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

.Hi Folks Im trying to set Javascript function to align (stretch) last child in FlexBox. 
To show max three columns in row i have on  . article-card-container is set `flex: 1 1 calc(100 * (1/3));`.

To stretch last item I need set on it  `flex: 1;`

```html
<div id="content-container">
<article class="article-card-container"></article>
<article class="article-card-container"></article>
<article class="article-card-container"></article>
<article class="article-card-container"></article>
</div>
```

Here is my solution that is working BUT ...

```js
window.onload = function alignLeftovers() {
    // get container with flexboxes
    var container = document.getElementById("content-container");
    // get container children
    var childernCount = container.children.length;
    // get leftover children
    var leftover = container.children.length % 3;

    if (childernCount > 3 && leftover === 1 ) { // condition
      // start loop
        for (var i = 0; i < container.children.length; i++) {
            // remove class on last child
            container.lastElementChild.classList.remove('article-card-container');
        }
        // add a new class on last child
        container.lastElementChild.classList.add('article-card-container-100');
    }
};
```

Im using `leftover === 1` for test because there are even 2 items leftover and `leftover > 0`  cause problems.

Problem of this function is that I had to write new class to be assigned (included all subclasses for inside elements = lots of code).

First condition in `if` statement is used because `modulus` was returning 1 even there were only two elements.

Is there better solution (Im new to JS) in pure JavaScript how to on last child class `.article-card-container` selector get to "flex" property and change (remove & add) its value and avoid to write brand new class?

Thanks for any suggestions or hints to make it better

Comment: no clear what you want to achieve, can you illustrate ?

Comment: Im creating WP theme and list of articles is different and max columns on row is 3. Because all flex elements have set flex value to 1/3 all Im trying is to remove this value to and stretch last child to 100%

Comment: so no need JS for this :) simple CSS would be enough

Comment: Its my first attempt to ask something and I get negative point. can someone explain why I got downvote for my Q?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm now aware to ask any more questions because I don know what a good question mean. I tried to sort JS code because  I did'n find right answer here and I have got downvote. I know there is 100 ways to sort one problem but I don't understand judging someone question only because is asked. At least I always trying to help others without judging them. So to who downvote. IM SORRY to ask

Comment: Here is help on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I did upvote as soon as wrote thanks to guys to help me. But system didn't accepted to show my upvote because I don't have 15 answers or something like that it just said thanks we accepted your upvote but... So what else I have to do to thanks and appreciate community help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `flex` of `lastElementChild` and `lastElementChild.previousElementSibling` to **`1`** if `leftover===2`

```js
window.onload = function alignLeftovers() {
  var container = document.getElementById("content-container");
  var childernCount = container.children.length;
  console.log(childernCount);
  var leftover = container.children.length % 3;
  if (childernCount > 3 && leftover === 1) {
    container.lastElementChild.style.flex = "1"
  } else if (childernCount > 3 && leftover === 2) {
    container.lastElementChild.style.flex = "1"
    container.lastElementChild.previousElementSibling.style.flex = "1"
  }
};
```

```css
#content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.article-card-container {
  width: 33.3333%;
  padding: 9px;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-container">
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer I'have tried very similar CSS style and it can partially sort problem, I mean when leftover is 1 (4,7, 10 ....) but how to sort situation where are 2 articles left over (in 5, 11 .. articles scenario) Thats why I tried to set function with conditions <code>leftover === 1 </code>to 100%  to test it and later set rules for 2 leftover elements to set flex to 50%. Is there any CSS solution for it? Im sorry not to be absolutely clear with initial Question

Comment: When 2 articles are left, how you want to aligned them?

Comment: To fit last line 50/50

Comment: This can be done using CSS alone ... check my answer

Comment: @LGSon Thank You

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with CSS only, and will be much more efficient than using script.

It is done by combining  the `nth-child`/`nth-last-child` and `last-child` selector, and will work on any number of items, with start from 1 item.

It work like that, when both the `nth-*` and `last-child` selector will match an element at the same time, the rule kicks in.

E.g., the `:nth-child(3n+1):last-child` rule will target every 3rd element, starting from the 1st, then 4th, 7th and so on, if it also is the last, and with this, select any single element on the last row.

The `:nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(2)` will do the same, though select it if it is the 2nd element, meaning there is 2 on the last row.

The final sibling selector `+` will target the immediate sibling if there were 2, which always also will be the last.

Stack snippet

```css
.content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.article-card-container {
  width: 33.3333%;
  padding: 9px;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*  if every 3rd, start from 1st, also being 2nd last + last */
.article-card-container:nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(2),
.article-card-container:nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(2) + article {
  width: 50%;
}

/*  if every 3rd, start from 1st, also being last  */
.article-card-container:nth-child(3n+1):last-child {          
  width: 100%;
}

/*  for demo styling  */
.content-container + .content-container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
</div>

<div class="content-container">
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
</div>

<div class="content-container">
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
  <article class="article-card-container"></article>
</div>
```